# Source of internet wireless: Mask connected devices behind router/device

Tags: router, wireless-router, dhcp

Which device/router do I need to use not an ethernet cable as source of internet but a wireless connection.

I want to connect to a (different) wireless network without it knowing how much or which devices of mine are connected, mask it behind my own device/router (with DHCP I guess) so to speak.

Comment: WLAN adapter of your choice

Comment: If this question has a good answer so far, why is it downvoted?

Comment: It's seeking an opinion on what hardware to use.  Hardware recommendations are not on topic.  You should read the help center.  I wouldn't call the answer you received, "good" to be honest, it's incomplete.

Comment: not if this problem can be solved through software... which is included in the question.

Comment: This cannot be solved by software, you cannot connect to a wireless access point through software if you don't have a wireless adapter to connect it to.  Software recommendations are also not on topic here at Superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, get a wireless bridge, I have two somewhere. With the wireless bridge it can turn a wireless signal into a Ethernet port, then connect the router of your choice up, turn on DHCP and they wont know what devices you connect.

Comment: When I search on Amazon (Germany) for it I cannot find anything. Can you tell me a specific cheap model that can act as a network bridge?

Comment: A wireless bridge is simply a wireless access point.  Research 802.11 access points.